# Inheritance with SqsListener

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, spring-messaging

I have a strange situation that I don't understand.
I would like to decide in a bean, should I enable or disable the SQS listener.
So I've created a config class with a definition:

```
@Bean
MyListener createListener(Features f){
  return f.shouldListen() ? new RealListener() : new MockListener();
}
```

As you can see, I have such an inheritance:

```
interface MyListener{}
```

```
class RealListener implements MyListener{
  @SqsListener(...)
  list handleMessage(SqsMessage message){
    ...
  }
}
```

```
class MockListener implements MyListener{}
```

Now, the funny part:

It **sometimes** works.

After few restarts of the application, the `handleMessage()` method is called but in most cases it isn't without any exception. The queue is created, all permissions are in place.
To make it working I need to return `RealListener` from `createListener()` method or move `@SqsListener` annotation to a method in the `MyListener` interface. Both are not options for me, because I don't want to call AWS, when the mock is enabled.

I've tried with conditional bean creation but as `Features` depends on a DB (indirect entityManager dependency, to be more precise), I can't make it working. I've tried with abstract class instead of interface, but without luck. I've tried to register the `RealListener` bean in the `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` but this also doesn't work (same `entityManager` dependency issue). I've tried to move the annotation to the interface and use `@ConditionalOnBean` with `@Primary` to create an empty `AmazonSqsClient` when the mock is enabled, but it doesn't work.

I could understand that it doesn't work, because the bean has to be created for a type with the method annotated with `@SqsListener` (not with it's supperclass/interface type), but I have three such beans and a lottery - sometimes all work, sometimes one or two but sometimes none of those.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Well... I've found the issue but it still would be nice, to know, what has happened.

So... There is a class `QueueMessageHandler` using `detectHandlerMethods(...)` method from the superclass `AbstractMethodMessageHandler`. This method uses `MethodIntrospector.selectMethods()` to select methods to scan. This class takes into consideration methods annotated with `@SqsListener` when there is `@EnableSqs` in some configuration class.
The problem is, in my project the `@EnableSqs` annotation is located in some file - not the file with `createListener(...)` method and not the main class of the Spring Boot application. That means, the class with `@EnableSqs` can be loaded before or after `MethodIntrospector.selectMethods()`.

The output is:

1. I have no idea, why it works fine without inheritance and doesn't work with inheritance
2. To fix the issue, I've moved `@EnableSqs` to the main class of the project